# Use a report for 2 or more systems with different databases

Tags: reporting-services

In my project I've a general folder for all my reports. I want to run these report for 2 different systems, (same server, different databases, same store procedure) 
after I deploy I created 2 folder and I moved the DataSource and the report into them and update the connection string for each database.

I've 2 issues:

1. In one the report runs ok but when I tried to edit my DataSource I got the error "An internal error occurred on the report server."
2. In second folder I can edit the DataSource to change the connection string but the report show values in 0

I'm guessing that I don't need to create Data Source in each folder, Am I in the right way to do that?

Comment: RE 1.  If you can post detailed error logs from the report server, that would help with the error.

RE 2.  "The report show values in 0"  Can you explain this further?  It's not clear what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating two different projects within a solution.  This will let you set the deployment settings for each project.  You can do all the copying on your local machine after you modify a report and then deploy.